# Check if element is in Array via includes() in Vue / Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I want to check if my barcode string is in the existing array of barcodes.
I found out that there is a function for that in Javascript called includes().

So I tried the following:

```
var Numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
console.log(Numbers.includes(1)) // True
```

That works perfectly.
But my version:

```
data() {
return {
  form: {
    items: [ //this is the array what I want to check
    ],
    //...
  },
}
```

In one of my functions I have this little snippet:

```
.then(response => {
      barcode = response.data;
      if (barcode.length > 0)
        if(!this.form.items.includes(barcode)) //THIS DON'T WORK
          this.form.items.push(barcode[0]);
      else
        this.$message({
        message: 'Wrong Barcode!',
        type: 'warning'
      }) 
  })
```

The array is empty because I push elements in it each time when I use the scanner.

Comment: I think in your example, `barcode` is `array`

Comment: change Numbers to numbers

Comment: Well, I don't want duplicates in the form.items-Array. The array were my barcodes are is called items. And barcode is the variable name for the strings, which I scan in.

Comment: if barcode is a string, why do you push `barcode[0]` ?

Comment: this seems like wrong logic     if (barcode.length > 0)  if(!this.form.items.includes(barcode))

Comment: The code does not help to understand the problem because important details are missing (how does response look like?). A full minimal working example would be better than a few code snippets. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and try to revise your question.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your barcode is an array, and item is an array of barcodes.
Try this

```
if (barcode.length > 0)
    if(!this.form.items.includes(barcode[0]))
      this.form.items.push(barcode[0]);
```

Comment: This don't work out. items should be an array of barcodes.

Comment: Items should be an array of barcodes, where barcodes is a string. You are pushing barcode[0] into the items array which should indicate barcode is not a string but an array of one string.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood barcode is an array and you want to push only the elements you have not collected yet (avoiding duplicates).

```
if (barcode.length > 0) {
  barcode.forEach(item => {
    if(!this.form.items.some(el => el === item)) {
      this.form.items.push(item);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Now I can't scan anymore. Even when the array is empty.